# custom addon in WooCommerce product in cart and order programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have 'addon' post_type and and its price are stored in meta data i.e. I can get price of addon by get_post_meta($addon_id,'add_on_price',true).

Now when a product (WooCommerce)  is added to a cart, user may select multiple addon and these addon will be added to cart along with product.

how would I add these addon to the cartand order.

Any suggestion will help me.
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this hook to add custom addon data to woocommerce object, order & emails.
https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-custom-data-woocommerce-order/

And you can use this code to add addon price to product.

```
function calculate_eyehole_fee( $cart_object ) {  
    global $isProcessed;
    if( !WC()->session->__isset( "reload_checkout" )) {

        $addonFee = 30.00;

        foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {

            $defPrice = $value['data']->get_price('edit');
            $value['data']->set_price((float) $defPrice + $addonFee);
        } 
        $isProcessed = true;  
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'calculate_eyehole_fee', 99 );
```

Comment: Thanks, for helping this ... it will help me a lot ..

Comment: Hi, one thing, though I have added add on price , but the additional price is not added while redirecting to paypal page while making order. Only the actual price is receiving on paypal. is there any hook for that ?